# About the size of rocksdb on custom cluster

Tags: solana-test-validator, ledger

this question to the developers, we have deployed our own Solana cluster, and there are almost no transactions there at the moment, but at the same time in ledger, namely rocksdb takes 1+ terabytes of memory after some short time, is it possible to fix it somehow ? We clearly have less data stored in the blockchain than 1 terabyte

is there no solution other than --limit-ledger-size ? Because I'd like to keep the old transactions in the cluster

Comment: `--limit-ledger-size` is the only way currently, unfortunately